# VBA automatically enables "macros" when workbook is open?

Tags: excel, vba, security

This may be a silly question, but can someone enable automatically the VBA scripts / macros when a workbook is open? Without going through the path file > options > security > macros > enable.

I know this is there for security reasons and this is probably not possible. it is just a question out of curiosity.

Comment: It's not possible... unless you [sign the macro digitally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769026/auto-enable-macro-with-digital-cert), or [force the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421843/excel-vba-enabling-macro-settings)

Comment: or unless you [enable all macros by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202246/trigger-macro-on-enabling-macros) which is not recommended though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Macro functionality has to be enabled for each user, or set by an admin using the registry.

Comment: Yeah, I imagined that, but there is probably a way. However, it probably must be by programing in the actual program that run office which I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Place the workbook in a Trusted Location.................

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010031999.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put all macros in a file personal.xlsm (Office 2007)and put this file in microsoft office XLSTART folder. Let it contain generic name of the files to be operated. This macrofile wiill open with all the macros when you open new instance of excel.Choose the macro in view macro. Rename your file to generic name specified in macro. Operate the macro then again change the file generic name to original name. Follow similiar process for other files. This way multiple macros can be operated on multiple files. Suitably adopt this approach to your version of Office. If you do not have administer privileges then you have to make a folder containing macro file as trusted location.